# AVCaptureDevice devices are empty

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, qr-code

I'm trying to create a QR code scanner with this [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/barcode-reader-swift/)

I don't get any devices.

```
let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInDualCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back)
print(deviceDiscoverySession.devices.isEmpty)//true
```

I checked similar questions

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46426003/avcapturedevice-doesnt-find-any-device) - I didn't see App Sandbox in Target Settings / Capabilities

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31119524/unable-to-get-devices-using-avcapturedevice) - I'm running the project in iPhone 6 real device, Not in simulator. And `AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: AVMediaType.video)` returns `.authorized`. I've added Camera access description in `info.plist`

Comment: What device are you using for testing?

Comment: @vpoltave I'm using iPhone 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all iPhones contain dual camera, that's why `devices` is empty.

You can try add this deviceTypes: `[.builtInWideAngleCamera]`.

> Here is all available [device types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/devicetype) for now.

Also there is a good answer to question about **Dual Camera** - [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41499418/6057764).

**Hope this will help you!**

Comment: Is it possible to use multiple deviceTypes with or condition. If dual camera isn't available use builtInWideAngleCamera?

Comment: @arunsiva `DiscoverySession` init takes an array of `AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType`, so you can try desire options and see how it will play out.

Comment: @arunsiva I edited answer and add link to all available device types